# Displaying the average rating of every record that has the same ID and record with no rating

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I want to display every record with their average rating and records with no rating with `foreach` loop. My problem is my code only displays records that has rating. Below is my code.

```
$packages = DB::table('packages')
                ->join('comments', function($join){
                    $join->on('comments.package_id', '=', 'packages.package_id');
                })
                ->join('agents', function($join){
                    $join->on('packages.agent_id', '=', 'agents.id');
                })
                ->select('comments.*', 'packages.*', 'agents.fname', 'agents.lname', 'agents.photo as agent_photo', 
                        DB::raw('AVG(rating) as ratings_average'))
                ->groupBy('comments.package_id')
                ->orderBy('packages.created_at', 'desc')
                ->paginate(8);
```

Comment: What does your database look like?

Comment: you probably just need to change your joins to left joins

Comment: I have 2 tables. (1) packages and (2) comments. Comments has the FK of `package_id`, and the rating which is an `int`.

Comment: @F.Lins THANK YOU!!!!!

Comment: @LaravelBegginer you should probably post your correct code and mark as resolved for future reference

Comment: - the problem is with your join, you are using inner join, to get the required result, use left join

Answer (score 0):

```
 $packages = DB::table('packages')
                ->leftJoin('comments', function($join){
                    $join->on('comments.package_id', '=', 'packages.package_id');
                })
                ->join('agents', function($join){
                    $join->on('packages.agent_id', '=', 'agents.id');
                })
                ->select('comments.*', 'packages.*', 'agents.fname', 'agents.lname', 'agents.photo as agent_photo', 
                        DB::raw('AVG(rating) as ratings_average'))
                ->groupBy('comments.package_id')
                ->orderBy('packages.created_at', 'desc')
                ->paginate(8);
```

I solved my problem, i just changed `inner join` to `left join`.